# Help with Rates of Change?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck with this question at the moment, can somebody help please? :)

A thermometer is taken from a room where the temperature is 22°C to the outdoors, where the temperature is −3°C. After one minute the thermometer reads 14°C. 
(a) What will the reading on the thermometer be after 4 more minutes? 
(b) When will the thermometer read −2°C? 
______ minutes after it was taken to the outdoors.

Thank you so much!

***** EDIT: This is what I got so far from a)

I represent the temp diff at time t as d.t 
d.t = d.0 e^(kt) 
= 25e^kt ............... 22-(-3) = 25 
d.1 = 25 e^k*1 
or 17 = 25 e^k ........... 17 = 14-(-3) 
so k = ln(17/25)

a. d.4 = 25e^((ln(17/25)*4) = 5.34 
so the temp = 5.34 -(-3) = 8.34 deg

Comment: Use newton's law of cooling.

Comment: I came up with a) = 5.34
and b) = 8.346
Be is correct but for some reason a) is incorrect. Could somebody calculate through and maybe that way I will find my mistake?

Comment: Suggest you put your calculation into the question.

Comment: Edited my progress in.